# Small UPDATE makes hang issue

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, freeze

PostgreSQL 9.5.

A very small update SQL uses very high CPU for a long time like a hang.
My Windows console application uses a simple UPDATE statement to update the latest time as follows.

```
UPDATE META_TABLE SET latest_time = current_timestamp WHERE host = 'MY_HOST'
```

There are just 2 console applications which issue above SQL.

- No index on META_TABLE.
- Only 1 row.
- When it is hanging, no lock information.
- UNLOGGED Table.
- IDLE status in pg_stat_activity
- Commit after UPDATE.

During that the hang time, I can INSERT or DELETE data with the table above.
After starting the application, about in 20 minutes, this issue happens.
I think it is not a SQL statement or table structure issue, probably something wrong in a database side.

Can you guess anything to resolve this issue?

## Update

There are 2 db connections in the console application. 1 for Select & 1 for DML.
I tried to close DML DB connection every 2 minutes. Then, I haven't seen the issue!! However, the hang issue happened on SELECT statement (also very simple SELECT).
It seems that there is a some limit per the session.
Now, I am also closing the Select db connection as well per 3 minutes and monitoring.

Comment: You have `SET = current_timestamp`.... aren't you missing a column name?

Comment: Miss the column name. Sorry. Issue remains.

Comment: *Only 1 row* In the entire table, or that will be affected by the UPDATE? If the latter, how many total rows are in the table?

Comment: Just 1 row but the table having several rows also got this issue. Most likely, in case there are small rows in a table, this issue occurs I guess.

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table?

Comment: No trigger and no dependent objects.

Comment: What performance for?

    select * from META_TABLE   WHERE host = 'MY_HOST'

Comment: No issue on SELECT the table. Very fast.